# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. I get when try to get data from Spring Data REST

Tags: java, axios, cors, spring-data-rest

I'm trying to fetch some data from the REST API.The backend is written in Java using Spring Data REST I have a repository and an entity created

```
public interface DisciplineRepository extends JpaRepository<Discipline, Integer> {
}

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "disciplines")
public class Discipline {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 30)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "discipline", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    Set<Task> tasks;
}
```

On the frontend I use axios and execute such request

```
export const simpleJSON = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/",
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json"
    }
});
const getUserDisciplines = (username: string) => {
    return simpleJSON.get<DisciplineData>(`/users/${username}/disciplineSet`)
    .then((response: any) => {
        return response.data._embedded.disciplines
               .sort((a: DisciplineData, b: DisciplineData) => a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1)
        }
    );
}
```

If I use curl everything works fine, but in the browser console I get this error

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: Have you configured your backend for CORS? If you haven't, read https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/. If you have, add your CORS configuration to your question.

Answer (score 1):

As the message suggests, there is **NO** 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header present.

Try adding the following header

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*"
```

Example

```
export const simpleJSON = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/",
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"


    }
});
```

**Note:**

Using "*" for Access-Control-Allow-Origin might resolve your error but it's not a recommended approach in production, please take a look at the following documentation
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS